# Undefined is not a function in Jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, undefined

I'm having a problem with some javascript I got help with. This is the error I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

It seems to be with my line:

```
callback(lastResult); // send the result back
```

The odd thing is the code seems to work as expected, but I obviously don't want to have errors with my code. Can someone please help to show me where I am going wrong?

**Jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/uaZkV/3/

**Full code:**

```
$(function () {
    var input = $("#loc"),
        lat = $("#lat"),
        lng = $("#lng"),
        lastQuery = null,
        lastResult = null, // new!
        autocomplete;

    function processLocation(callback) { // accept a callback argument
        var query = $.trim(input.val()),
            geocoder;

        // if query is empty or the same as last time...
        if (!query || query == lastQuery) {
            callback(lastResult); // send the same result as before
            return; // and stop here
        }

        lastQuery = query; // store for next time

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({
            address: query
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                lat.val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                lng.val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                lastResult = true; // success!
            } else {
                alert("Sorry - We couldn't find this location. Please try an alternative");
                lastResult = false; // failure!
            }
            callback(lastResult); // send the result back
        });
    }

    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[0], {
        types: ["geocode"],
        componentRestrictions: {
            country: "uk"
        }
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', processLocation);

    $('#searchform').on('submit', function (event) {
        var form = this;

        event.preventDefault(); // stop the submission

        processLocation(function (success) {
            if (success) { // if the geocoding succeeded, submit the form
                form.submit()
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: You should also read [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: Looks like query is getting the value undefined!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', processLocation);
> ```

If you add `processLocation` as a maps event listener, it will get no arguments passed when the event fires. The `callback` argument is `undefined` then, and causing your exception (though not stopping your control flow, as it's the last statement).

That means you will check whether an actual `callback` function was passed before invoking it:

```
function processLocation(callback) { // accept a callback argument
    var query = $.trim(input.val()),
        geocoder;

    // if query is empty or the same as last time...
    if (!query || query == lastQuery) {
        if (typeof callback=="function")
            callback(lastResult); // send the same result as before
        return; // and stop here
    }

    lastQuery = query; // store for next time

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
        address: query
    }, function (results, status) {
        lastResult = status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK;
        if (lastResult) {
            lat.val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
            lng.val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
        } else {
            alert("Sorry - We couldn't find this location. Please try an alternative");
        }
        if (typeof callback=="function")
            callback(lastResult); // send the result back
    });
}
```

If you have multiple invocations of `callback` and don't want to perform the typecheck everywhere, you also could define a

```
function noOperation() {}
```

and use that as a default value for `callback` if none is passed:

```
function processLocation(callback) { // accept a callback argument
    if (typeof callback != "function")
        callback = jQuery.noop; // predefined by jQuery
    …
}
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at this and explaining it. Is this implemented as you suggested? http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/uaZkV/11/

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) for `google.maps.event.addListener` implies that when it calls the callback function (`processLocation`) it does so without any arguments.

`callback` is the first argument of your function definition for `processLocation`, so it is `undefined` when called by the Google Maps code.

You try to call it as a function without testing if it is one.

Either remove that attempt to call it, or test it with `typeof` first.